# intermitent lines between :before and :after elements on certain Zoom measurements.

Tags: css

```
.green-right:before{content:"";width: 0; height: 0;border-left: 9px solid transparent;border-right: 5px solid #53C6D3;border-bottom: 9px solid transparent;border-top: 9px solid transparent;position: absolute;top:0; left:-14px;}
.green-right {margin:5px 0px 5px -6px; width:12px;height:18px; left:50%; cursor:pointer; float:left;background-color:#53C6D3;position: relative; padding:0 !important;}
.green-right:after{content: ""; z-index:1;width: 0; float:left;position: absolute;left: 12px; border-left: 5px solid #53C6D3;border-right: 9px solid transparent;border-bottom: 9px solid transparent;border-top: 9px solid transparent;}
```

---

the above code creates this element:

[image]

---

As you can see, on certain screen widths, I"m getting these white lines between the before and after elements. How do I prevent this from happening?

---

here is a codepen: [CodePen](http://codepen.io/tdsjr82/pen/yNwyRr)

when you zoom in and out, you can see the unwanted line / lines.

Comment: Post your HTML as well.

Comment: Is this in all browsers or just one? Offhand it could just be subpixel rendering.

Comment: Seems to be in all browsers.

Comment: Are you sure that your zoom is set to default (1) when you load your page?

Comment: This happens because you zoom - not because of screen width. Browsers handle CSS created graphics and zooming badly. If you want to test in different screen width, use something like Google Chrome's Device Mode (F12 -> toggle device mode.)

Comment: You're right. I"ll update that in the description. How do I correct this behavior ?